# composition of principal bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I am struggling to figure out what is wrong with my following conclusion:

> Let $A \overset{f}\longrightarrow B$ be a principal $F$-bundle and $B \overset{g}\longrightarrow C$ be a principal $G$-bundle. Now by definition of a principal bundle, we know that for every point $c$ in $C$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $c$ such that $g^{-1}(U) \cong U \times G$. If we do the same for $f$ using neighborhoods obtained from $g$, we get $$f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}(U) \cong U \times F \times G$$
> This means that $A \overset{g \circ f}\longrightarrow C$ is a principal $F \times G$-bundle.

In other words, above conclusion tells us that composition of two mentioned principal bundles just comes from the following trivial central extension $$1 \to F \to F \times G \to G \to 1$$
But we know that there are non-trivial central extensions of $G$  by $F$, so we can have compositions of principal $G$-bundles with principal $F$-bundles which are not just $F \times G$-bundles.

Comment: Your argument only gives a homeomorphism but it doesn't say anything about the actions of $F$ and $G$ so you haven't learned anything about the structure group of the composition yet.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! I think I got your point. In the definition of a principal bundle, we need commutativity of some diagram and also an action of the structure group on the total space. As I understood, for some compositions of principal bundles, we can define an action of the product of structure groups on the total space satisfying required conditions, but it's not true in general?

Comment: Well, just try it! Can you define an action of any structure group at all?